# codeigniter hosting issue session_start(): Cannot send session cookie

Tags: codeigniter, session

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpWNV.jpg)I have created a web system using codeigniter. I don't have any errors while testing it in local host. after hosting the website to live host it generates some errors which cannot resolved. The errors is "session_start(): Cannot send session cookie ". I searched regarding this issue and did all possible changes in coding and config file. I have clearly define the session saving location in config. Also when I try to remove all session functionalities in my website, it generate another error which is "base_url() is not a function". Please guide further with solution. thanks all.

Comment: Sometimes when you have named file and class incorrect can cause some errors Make sure you controllers and models files and classes only have first letter upper case. Explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Yea. the development was done following to the codeigniter documentation. and all meaningful procedures were followed in the website. still I can' t find a solution

Answer (score 0):

In `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Bang!

UPDATE: Regardless `base_url()` make sure you have the `url` helper loaded in the autoload.

Comment: tried, still same issue , not solving . anyhow thanks for the answer

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't help.